# How to calculate the current page if the items per page changes to a smaller number?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have the following issue - I have a pagination, that shows which part of the records you are looking at.

For example:

**Total Items:** 100 
**Possible Items per Page:** 10, 25

If I set the items per page to `10` and go to page six this will get me the following:

```
51-60/100
  *   *
  |   |--------- Total records
  | 
  |-------- Displayed range of records
```

If change the page items per page to `25` it will be set to `51-75/100`. But if I set it back to `10` it will display me `71-80`.

It somehow feels like a weird behaviour, and I am sure, that the calculation that I came up with is faulty. I would think, that the right result should be `51-60` -> (set to `25` per Page) -> `51-75` -> (set to `10` per Page) -> `51-60`

Here is my code:

```js
itemsPerPageChanged(newItemsPerPage) {
    // On every change of the items per page the total amount of pages changes
    this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / newItemsPerPage);

    // Here I calculate the current page depending on the itemsPerPage size
    this.page = Math.ceil((this.itemsPerPage * this.page) / newItemsPerPage);

    // If the current page is bigger than total possible pages the ceil went to far and we take the last possible page as current page
    if (this.page > this.totalPages) this.page = this.totalPages;

    this.itemsPerPage = newItemsPerPage;
    this.getItems();
},
```

What is the right formula? I just can't get my head around it right now. :(

Comment: can you reset page (P) from 5 to 1 on page length (L) changed? P can not be kept with L = 25 in your cases

Comment: hmm, with L = 25 and P = 5, the current range 51-75/100 seems incorrect, right? It should be 101-125 or whatever like that

Comment: Actually no - we start with L=10 and P=5 which maps to L=25 and P=3. The items that you would find on page five when L is set to 10 are on page 3 if you set L to 25.

Comment: _"If I set the items per page to 10 and go to page five this will get me the following: 51-60/100"_ - so you start counting your pages at 0 then? Because if not, then page 5 with ten results per page, should be items 41-50. (1: 1-10, 2: 11-20, 3: 21-30, 4: 31-40, 5: 41-50)

Comment: Try to replace by `Math.floor` at the line of `Math.ceil((this.itemsPerPage * this.page) / newItemsPerPage);` and let me know if it's not fit your conditions.

Comment: @ThanhDao `Math.floor` did not help.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, exactly

Comment: @codlix Show your function which generate the range

Comment: What, _why_? Do you pagination links on the frontend also start with "[0] [1] [2] ..." then? That would be highly unusual.

Comment: _"we start with L=10 and P=5 which maps to L=25 and P=3."_ - that makes no sense. If you arrive at the first item to display, which is number 50, by calculating `10 * 5` - then this should "map to" `25 * 2` as well then.

Comment: @codlix Let me reproduce the steps. Firstly with L = 10 and P = 5 => 51-60. So change L = 25 then P = 3 (because new range is 51-70)? After that, change back L = 10, what actually the range you expected? If it should be 51-60 => P = 6. I think you missed the "Range start" value in calculation P.

Comment: My bad - obviously it is 51-60 -> P=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have first page's number 1, you should calculate page in the following way:

```
const pageFirstItemIndex = this.itemsPerPage * (this.page - 1) + 1;
this.page = Math.ceil(pageFirstItemIndex / newItemsPerPage);
```

and

```
displayedRangeOfRecords = `${itemsPerPage * (page - 1) + 1}-${itemsPerPage * page}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code sample and it works for me, if

```
displayedRangeOfRecords = `${this.itemsPerPage * this.page + 1}-${this.itemsPerPage * (this.page + 1)}`;
```

P.S. L=10 and P=5 maps to L=25 and P=2 (not P=3)